# How to pass file properties from parent to child flow using "When a HTTP request is received"

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, power-automate, solution

I am trying to create a solution that will be triggered from multiple libraries across different sites within SharePoint, for this I would like to use a parent flow for each library to initiate a child flow that does most of the work. The trigger for the parent flows will be "For a selected file". The child flow will use the file details to e-mail file information and update a column.

I am quite new to some of this and I've got a bit stuck getting file information to pass through to the child flow. With the child flow I'm using "When a HTTP request is received".

I have created a test solution to see if I can achieve this:

[Flow examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hMuD.jpg)

Could someone point me in the right direction to be able to pass the information correctly to the child flow, so I can then use the properties from the file there?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create **Input** parameters in the Child Flow Trigger.
And those will be available in the parent to pass values.

Here is MS Article at [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform-release-plan/2019wave2/power-automate/call-child-flows) says:

**Building the child flow**

You'll first need to create the child flow. Today, there are three different triggers you can use for child flows:

1. Manually trigger a flow (under the Flow button for mobile).
2. Power Apps.
3. When an HTTP request is received (available only on the premium HTTP request/response connector).

When you select the first trigger you can define inputs that you want the child flow to receive from the parent flow. For example, if the child flow is going to be creating a contact, it will need the Contact name and Contact email. Select Add an input and provide the details.

**Child Flow**

[image]

**Parent Flow - parameters available**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply Matiur. It's not so much that part I'm having trouble with as I've been able to pass an email address and text through. It's the part where I'm passing through the file content from the parent and then need to understand how to get the information out of that object in the child flow (please see the screenshots). Thank you.

Comment: In the parent, where are you getting the file content from? If you are retrieving it from some source, like SharePoint, you can pass the ID from Parent to Child and retrieve the content in the Child.